# Writing a script to run commands inside a console

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, metasploit

I'm writing a script to automate metasploit now my script works fine till the commands i need to run on the terminal but when i try to run the commands which i have to execute inside the metasploit console the script stops until i manually exit the console, and then it will resume from the next line.

when you run metasploit it opens a console (msfconsole) inside the terminal where you can run your commands.

how can i add specific commands in my script to run inside the console??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts, in general, will run a command and wait for it to execute.  Only once the process launched by the command finishes will your script move on to the next command.

`metasploit` can be used in interactive mode, and that seems to be what you're trying to do.  That means the `msfconsole` is the process that's created and so the script won't continue until that process terminates.

You could look at using something like `expect` to interact with a program that expects input while it's running.  Alternately, many things you want to do in metasploit can be done without an interactive session so you could try to find those sets of commands and use them instead.

Comment: where can i find those set of commands to run a non-interactive session?

Comment: @HeroicJokester You can look [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfcli/) which does say that `msfcli` is apparently deprecated, but to use the `-x` flag to `msfconsole`, so that may well be your solution really

Comment: Yes bro that worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch! :D